# file not found / unable to import package

Tags: go, grpc, goland, grpc-go

I have been following a gRPC tutorial, this works perfectly fine. The problems start when I try to add https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway to my project. I use the commands they give you:

```
go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/protoc-gen-swagger
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

and I import the package in my proto:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

I am getting an error on the line above saying "file not found".
When I copy the files inside my project, they are found but when I run the command

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
  -I$GOPATH/src \
  -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis \
  --go_out=plugins=grpc:. \
  path/to/your_service.proto
```

it will complain that it cannot find the files.

Could someone please tell me the correct way on how to be able to get this grpc-gateway working properly?

I am currently on windows with GoLand as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this issue correct it's the same that you have. They say you have to put these files in your repository https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/1065#issuecomment-544241612